# Is it correct to say 'mistakes in understanding'?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say 'mistakes in understanding' or a similar expression? For example: 'there is a mistake in your understanding.'

I am confused about this since I assume that 'understanding' refers to something that has been understood, is known, and is true. If so, a mistaken understanding seems to be a contradiction, similar to saying that something is a 'false truth.'

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with "misunderstand"?

Comment: 'Misunderstand' is perfectly fine, but I have also encountered expressions such as the above, and I wonder whether they make sense.

Comment: Apparently over half a million Google hits for "mistake in their understanding". You can check a few to see whether the context seems well written and logical.

Comment: Yes, it is. There's nothing ungrammatical about it, but I 100% agree with @Cascabel: "What is wrong with "misunderstand?" "Misunderstand" is clear and concise. On your question about it being an oxymoron or a contradiction in terms, know that it isn't. Yes, in some definitions of "understand," it is, like "to be thoroughly familiar with; apprehend clearly the character, nature, or subtleties of" (see def. 2 - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/understand), but in others, it isn't, like "to assign a meaning to; interpret: (see def. 3 - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. There's nothing ungrammatical about it. As @Edwin Ashworth clearly demonstrates in his comments above, there's significant evidence of usage.

That said, I 100% agree with what @Cascabel had to say: "What is wrong with 'misunderstand'?" "Misunderstand" (e.g., "You misunderstand," "You somewhat misunderstand.") is clear and concise, effective and efficient. Why use seven words to say what you can say in just two or three? Generally, succinctness is preferred. But dealer's choice.

On your question about it being an oxymoron or a contradiction in terms, no, it isn't. I mean, yes, in some definitions of "understand," like "to be thoroughly familiar with; apprehend clearly the character, nature, or subtleties of" (see def. 2 of "[understand](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/understand)"), it would be an oxymoron or contradiction in terms, but in other definitions, no, it wouldn't be, like "to assign a meaning to; interpret" (see def. 3 of "[understand](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/understand)").

When "mistake" or "mistakes" is used in phrases like "a mistake in understanding" and "mistakes in understanding," the use of "mistake" clearly eliminates the possibility of *thorough familiarity and clear apprehension*, so we can readily infer that any definition of "understanding" conveying that or conveying *correctness* isn't being used. Instead, we can readily infer that a meaning of "understanding" conveying *meaning assigned* or *interpretation* is being used, specifically how a person or people have perceived the matter be, which may not be correct, meaning in some uses of the word "understanding," one's "understanding" may have one earnestly believing one has fully and properly apprehended matters at hand when maybe one hasn't.